# Is there an equivalent tool to Appium for windows Application (not mobile)?

Tags: automated-tests, appium, robotframework, ui-automation

I use to work with Appium for mobile automation, now i want to use the same logic of Appium but for windows desktop application.
Is there any automation tool similar to Appium but to test desktop windows application?
(Other than RIDE and AutoIt) i 'm using ride with Sikuli library but i find that Is not as good as Appium which offer a many locations strategies by name,by id, by xpath ... there is no good strategy to locate elements only by image using `SikuliLibrary` or mouse click position using `AutoItLibrary` so that if i change from Windows 7 to 10 image will not respond to our scripts ....

Comment: yes it's GUI, but while the Library sikuli compare images, even effect color of windows between windows 7 and 10, images will be unknown !

Comment: This question is rather broad and some may find that it falls under the 4th [off-topic category](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  It helps to be specific as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sikuli and Appium are two different types of application and test approaches. This is well beyond the scope of SO and I urge you to look elsewhere for that type of information.

Within the Robot Framework community a number of official/common libraries exist. These are well known and easily found. However, there are also a large group of libraries that are not found in the Python Repository but freely available on (example) GitHub. On top of this there are the plain Python modules that can be directly imported and whose methods are then usable as keywords. If your favorite application has a Python interface or module, then creating a Robot Framework Library is not difficult.

Given the specific topic of Windows Desktop Application testing with Robot Framework my first search result lead me to the Official [Python Testing Tools Taxonomy](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy) Page for testing and it's [GUI testing section](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy#GUI_Testing_Tools). From this list the [PyWinAuto](https://pywinauto.github.io/) project shows most promise as it supports windows and is open source. A Robot Framework Library [robotframework-winbot](https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-winbot/) exists, and still works but has not been updated in a while.

As you mentioned Appium, I've also taken a look there and although the [Robot Framework Library](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary) [keyword documentation](http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html) doesn't seems to support Windows application, Appium itself has recently released some support for [Windows Application UI Testing](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#windows-application-ui-testing). This is based on the fairly new [Microsoft Windows Application Driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver). Python sypport is available, as there are Python examples in the [Python Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/Python) section, but no specific Robot Framework Library.

There may be other options, but I recommend you try these first and raise specific questions when you encounter issues.